# Sqlite bind text with void method?

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I use this code to perform functions in sqlite in Objective-c, in my case, I performed some searches on the internet and not found meaning and an example for these last two values in the code below:

```
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [tb UTF8String], -1, nil);
```

What mean `-1` and `nil` values inside my command? I believe that instead of `nil` can call a `void` method, can someone give me an example?

Comment: You can't be bothered to read the sqlite3 documentation then?

Comment: @trojanfoe I only see this https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html, in this link he say that void(*)(void*), but he don't give me an example..

Comment: Well look at the sentence starting "The fifth argument to the BLOB and string binding interfaces is a destructor used to dispose of the BLOB or string after SQLite has finished with it.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
char *value = strdup("somevalue");
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, value, -1, free);
```

In this case `strdup()` creates a copy of the string which must be freed using `free()` and sqlite3 will call this "destructor" function when disposing of the statement.

Comment: And -1 is a length of the text, right? -1 is here but the length is infinite right?

Comment: No, it's the result of calling `strlen()` on the value.  It means "this is a nul-terminated string".